# Representation matrix respect to the standard basis of Euclidean Space $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $X = \{(1,0,1), (1,1,0), (0,1,1)\}$ and $P$ is an orthogonal projection over $X$. Determine the representation matrix $P$ respect to the standard basis of Euclidean space $\mathbb{R} ^3$

I have trouble in the first step. Should I find every orthogonal projections of the vector in $X$ or what? I think it will lead to wrong computations later. 
Please help me.

Comment: Are you sure of your $X$? Span $(X)$ is the whole space $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Yeah, the problem statement said like that.